# How to make the contact autocomplete in Webform Civicrm to search for contacts that contain a search term, not start with

Tags: webform-civicrm

When you add an existing contact field to Webform Civicrm the autocomplete searches for contacts that start with the search term. How do you change the autocomplete function to search for contacts that contain the search term in any part of the name, not just the beginning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In search preferences /civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1: Automatic Wildcard should be "yes" to search for contacts that contain the search term in any part of the name.

Comment: It's a working solution but not a perfect one as it also influences the normal contact search form the civicrm admins use and also the general performance. Maybe it should be possible to inject a hidden % via code in the search which will trigger the wildcard behaviour or to add a parameter to the civicrm search api that can set wildcard behaviour.